# why Circle.circumference return error? and need to add () to make it work?

Tags: python-3.x

The assignment asked to set an instant variable `self.radius` in `Circle` instructor, and equal to `diameter` that get passed in. Then define `circumference` for `Circle` object that only take one argument `self`, and return the circumference of a circle with the given radius by this formula: `circumference = 2 * pi * radius`. Then print out `circumference` of `medium_pizza` which `diameter` is `12`

I wrote the below code. but when I run the code, it gives me this error`<bound method Circle.circumference of <__main__.Circle object at 0x7f75b5bfc588>>`.

I did change my code later by `print(medium_pizza.circumference())` (add a ()) and it works, but I could not wrap my mind around it. Why `radius` result could print out without a `()`, but `circumference` could not.

I do have another question I really hope someone could help me out. Since `def __init__` return `none`, why I can still get `radius` result. I thought I have to write `return self.radius` to get radius result.

```
class Circle:
  pi = 3.14
  def __init__(self, diameter):
    print("Creating circle with diameter {d}".format(d=diameter))
    # Add assignment for self.radius here:
    self.radius = diameter / 2
  def circumference(self):
    self.circumference= 2 * self.pi * self.radius
    return self.circumference

medium_pizza = Circle(12)
print(medium_pizza.circumference)
print(medium_pizza.radius)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you defined circumference as a method in your class, so it override the property you defined in the same method.
Basically:

```
def circumference(self):
    self.circumference = 2 * self.pi * self.radius
    return self.circumference
```

Is a method, in which you've defined `self.circumference` as a property, but `Circle.circumference` is still a method, because the property you defined does not override that value, hence the `bound method` part in your "error", this isn't an error though, because python is actually giving you exactly what you want, which is a pointer to the method defined as `circumference`, this is useful if you want to redefine the name of the function as something else later, like `my_new_func = medium_pizza.circumference` this binds `my_new_fun` to `medium_pizza`'s circumference method, which you could then call using `my_new_func()` instead of `medium_pizza.circumference()` because they both point to the same method now.

If you don't understand that, that's okay, I don't think your assignment was asking you to understand that anyway, but it's worth noting.  The important thing is that `medium_pizza.circumference` is a method name, so it returns a method address, unless you use `medium_pizza.circumference()` which invokes the method.

As for the second part of your question, `__init__(self):` does actually have a return type, and it is `self`, which is a Circle

The reason you don't have to return `self.radius` is because you've assigned radius as a property of the class, python does properties a little differently, so it might be a little confusing, but that's how you do it.

Classes are different than functions, to see more about how to use classes, take a look at the python documentation, it's pretty good [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).  Though, at your level, I'd advise taking a look [here instead](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-i/tutorial/), it's a bit more straightforward.

### With that, let's do an example:

Suppose I have a class

```
class pizza():
    pi = 3.14
    def __init__(self, diameter):
        self.toppings = []
        self.radius = diameter / 2
    def cirumference(self):
        return 2 * self.pi * self.radius
    def add_topping(self, topping):
        self.toppings.append(topping)
    def get_top_topping(self):
        return self.toppings[0] if len(self.toppings) > 0 else None
```

kinda complicated, but not really

I've defined a pizza class which takes a diameter, and is initialized with two properties `toppings` and `radius`. So I can do the following:

```
my_pizza = pizza(12)
print(my_pizza.radius)  # Will print out 6
print(my_pizza.toppings)  # Will print out []
```

Now I can call methods of this pizza object to modify its properties, or to get information

```
print(my_pizza.circumference())  # Will print 2pi*radius <- Note this is a method
my_pizza.add_topping("anchovies")  # Adds "anchovies" to the toppings list
print(my_pizza.toppings)  # Will print ["anchovies"] <- Note this is a property
print(my_pizza.get_top_topping())  # Will print "anchovies"
```

If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I can add more information.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much for this comment! So after reading your comment, this is what I take if it make sense:   `self.circumference` and `self.radius` is property, so when I try to print out the value, I don't need to use (). However, since I defined the `circumference`, so `Circle.circumference` became a method. In order to print out the value, I need to use (). For the second part of my question: `self.radius` is property so no need to return. ----------And does this mean for the `circumference` method, I don't need to return `self. circumference` either to get the value, is that correct?

Comment: In the case of the `circumference` method, you do need to return a value, this is because it's a method, and not a property.